# MS Excel: Find Last Occurrence of Specific Text Across Multiple Columns in a List and Return Matching Cell Value

Tags: excel, search, extract

Using MS Excel (Not VBA), I would like a formula that searches across multiple Cells A2:D2 (and downward) to find and retrieve the last occurrence of a specific keyword found in a List "Keywords (Find What)" located in G2:G5.  If last occurrence of keyword is found in either cells A2:D2, then extract/return the matching value of the content in Cell E2.

I've attempted to use this formula: =IFERROR(HLOOKUP("*"&G$5&"*",A2:D2,1,FALSE),""), Unfortunately it does not allow to search from a list, nor does it find the last occurrence.

See Illustration Example below for assistance:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`/`SEARCH`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:D2,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A2:D2)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(($G$2:$G$5),A2:D2)),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow... Thank you very much Basic, I'm thoroughly impressed and appreciative to your formula that works perfectly.  I would ask, similarly but not required, within your formula, can it be done so in reverse, by finding the first occurrence versus last occurrence.  Thanks.

Comment: @Miaka3 yes, change first argument of ```AGGREGATE``` function to ```15```

Comment: Hi Basic,  Thank you so much for the reply.  Also, I just realized unlike the example I provided whereas the data starts via Cell A2:D2; my actual data in my spreadsheet is M2:Q2.  When I entered the provided formula in R2, it does not to search across M2:Q2 it does not identify and extract, as it does in your provided formula.  Are you able to further assist.. Thanks Advance.

Comment: Then you should extend ```INDEX``` range (first argument of ```INDEX``` function) from ```A2:D2``` to ```A2:Q2```. Other ranges change to yours,

Comment: Miraculous, again thanks and thank you.. You've really been of great help than I can say... Thanks